# "Object is not callable" error in web crawler

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def lolz(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://www.thenewboston.com/search.php?type=1&sort=pop&page=' + str(page)
        sorce_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = sorce_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.findall('a',{'class' : 'item-name'}):
            href = link.get('href')
            print(href)
        page += 1
lolz(1)
```

Here is the code. I keep getting `Error: nonetype object is not callable`

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: line 12 ,for link in soup.findall('a',{'class' : 'item-name'}):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a typo, use `findAll`:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a',{'class' : 'item-name'}):
```